# Bluetooth with Kernel 3.18 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kernel, bluetooth

I'm running the kernel

```
me@me:~$ uname -r
3.18.0-031800-generic
```

because I need support for MST. Since I've installed this, I cannot connect with my bluetooth headset(or mobile phone). For a short time it seems to connected but then aborted.
running

```
me@me:~$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep bluetooth
May  6 19:21:18 me kernel: [ 4596.664763] init: bluetooth main process (8274) killed by ABRT signal
May  6 19:21:18 me kernel: [ 4596.664776] init: bluetooth main process ended, respawning
May  6 19:21:18 me bluetoothd[8460]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101
May  6 19:21:18 me bluetoothd[8460]: Starting SDP server
May  6 19:21:18 me bluetoothd[8460]: DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled
May  6 19:21:18 me bluetoothd[8460]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
May  6 19:21:18 me bluetoothd[8460]: Failed to init proximity plugin
May  6 19:21:18 me bluetoothd[8460]: Failed to init time plugin
May  6 19:21:18 me bluetoothd[8460]: Failed to init alert plugin
May  6 19:21:18 me bluetoothd[8460]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
May  6 19:21:18 me bluetoothd[8460]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
May  6 19:21:18 me bluetoothd[8460]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
May  6 19:22:49 me bluetoothd[8460]: input-headset driver probe failed for device 44:D4:E0:01:9A:06
May  6 19:22:49 me bluetoothd[8460]: Unknown command complete for opcode 19
May  6 19:22:49 me bluetoothd[8460]: Adapter /org/bluez/8460/hci0 has been enabled
May  6 19:23:07 me bluetoothd[8460]: Host is down (112)
May  6 19:23:17 me bluetoothd[8460]: Adapter /org/bluez/8460/hci0 has been disabled
May  6 19:23:17 me bluetoothd[8460]: Unregister path: /org/bluez/8460/hci0

me@me:~$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0c45:64d2 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

is there any way to solve this problem?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the results from `lsusb`

Comment: bluetooth is build in, but i added lsusb also

Comment: Are any files listed in `ls /lib/firmware/intel`

Comment: `me@me:~$ ls /lib/firmware/intel/
ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.1.2d.d.bseq   ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq   ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq    ibt-hw-37.7.bseq                    ibt-hw-37.8.bseq
ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq  ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq
`

Comment: I am not sure what to tell you as I loaded the same kernel on my laptop and it was able to connect to my phone and send files.  Have you tried Ubuntu 15.04 as the 3.19 kernel should provide MST support.  What was your old kernel in 14.04?